# How to get the size of an already-opened File in Rust?

Tags: file, rust

How can I get the size/length of the file that is declared as a `File` variable?

There is an option for getting it using the file name via `fs::metadata`:

```
let x = fs::metadata(file_path)?.len();
```

But I have a file that I already created and edited:

```
let mut my_file = File::create(file_path).unwrap();
my_file.write_all(buffer) // buffer is a data which comes from network and put into Vec<u8>

// From here, does it possible to get my_file length?
// Looking something like my_file.len();
```

Are there any function that gives the length of the `File`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a few options.

1. If you create the file like you did (`File::create`), you will truncate the file, which means it will set the size of that file to `0` and write the content of `buffer` to the file. This means that your file will now have the length `buffer.len()`.
2. Use [`File::metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.metadata) to get the metadata and therefore get the length of the file. Keep in mind that you have to sync the file (by using [`File::sync_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.sync_all)) with the underlying filesystem to update the metadata and get the correct value.
3. Use [`Seek::seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#tymethod.seek) which `File` implements. You can then get the current offset by using `my_file.seek(SeekFrom::End(0))` which will tell you the last position available.
4. On nightly (expected for release 1.35.0), you can use [`Seek::stream_len`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Seek.html#method.stream_len), which, unlike `seek(SeekFrom::End(0))`, restores the previous seek position.

Answer (score 42):

The `std::fs::File` provides a [`metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.metadata) method. It can be used with your `my_file` like this:

```rust
my_file.metadata().unwrap().len();
```